# Why can't pytest-qt find PyQt for Python 3.4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pytest-qt

I am using AppVeyor (Think Travis but for Windows) to run some tests again several different versions of Python. The tests depend on PyQt and pytest-qt. In some configurations, pytest-qt can't find PyQt, complaining:

> pytest-qt requires either PySide, PySide2, PyQt4 or PyQt5 to be installed

The PyQt5 tests are working, but the tests also need to run older versions of Python, where PyQt4 is required.

### Python 2.7, 32-bit

On Python 2.7 (32 bit), I install PyQt with conda:

```
conda install -q pyqt=4
```

It successfully installs pyqt-4.11.4-py27_7

Then I install pytest-qt with pip:

```
pip install pytest pytest-cov pytest-qt
```

It successfully installs pytest-qt-2.4.0.

Then I run the tests. It's fine.

### Python 2.7, 64-bit

Exactly the same story. Works fine.

### Python 3.4, 64-bit

This time it installs pyqt 4.11.4-py34_7, plus the same version of pytest-qt, but when the test runs, it crashes out:

```
py.test tests -v
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 174, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config._do_configure()
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 957, in _do_configure
INTERNALERROR>     self.hook.pytest_configure.call_historic(kwargs=dict(config=self))
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 628, in call_historic
INTERNALERROR>     res = self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 76, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pytestqt\plugin.py", line 187, in pytest_configure
INTERNALERROR>     qt_api.set_qt_api(config.getini('qt_api'))
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\miniconda34-x64\lib\site-packages\pytestqt\qt_compat.py", line 60, in set_qt_api
INTERNALERROR>     raise RuntimeError(msg)
INTERNALERROR> RuntimeError: pytest-qt requires either PySide, PySide2, PyQt4 or PyQt5 to be installed
Command exited with code 3
```

I tried specifying the environment variable `PYTEST_QT_API=pyqt4` or `PYTEST_QT_API=pyqt4v2`, but it complained:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I can't figure out what might be different for Python 3.4. What do I need to do to help pytest-qt find the installation of PyQt?